# Explanation for concept of relative density

Tags: pressure, density, fluid-statics, buoyancy

I am in class $9^{th}$, I'm reading my physics book in which it is written that: $$\mathrm{Relative\ Density} = \frac{\mathrm{Weight\ of\ solid\ in\ air}}{\mathrm{Loss\ of\ weight\ of\ solid\ in\ water}}$$ 
As I mention my level that I'm in class $9^{th}$, Plaese help me to understand this in easy method.[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of Free Body Diagram and Newton's Laws of motion?

Comment: @Benjamin Only with Newton's Laws of motion & not with Free Body Diagram .

Comment: The definition doesn't make any sense to me. Based on that definition the relative density of air would be zero, which is absolutely meaningless. For starters, density is defined as mass/volume, not weight per volume and one should certainly not mix the buoyancy in air into a density definition.

Comment: By Free Body Diagram, we basically mean showing ALL forces acting on an object. Does that sound familiar?

Comment: @Benjamin Now Ok

Comment: Try to have two scenarios: (1) a solid with known mass and volume hanging from a string  (2) The same situation except now the solid is completely submerged into water with known density. Show ALL forces acting on the solid in both scenarios. As CuriousOne mentioned, be careful with the buoyant force acting from the fluid to the solid cube and the fact that two strings would experience different tensions (call the first To and the second T). From each scenario you have two equations where the left-hand sides would be sum of the forces and right-hand sides equal to 0 due to equilibrium.

Comment: Plus, you need to know that relative density is defined as the ratio of a solid's density to that of the water. You can substitute required terms from the above argue.

Comment: As far as I can tell both Wikipedia and your textbook seem to be wrong about this equality. The relative density of two substances is given by $\rho_R = {{\rho_1}\over{\rho_2}}$, while the hydrostatic weighing method gives the ratio $\rho_{Rhydrostatic}={{\rho-\rho_{Air}}\over{\rho_{Water}-\rho_{Air}}}$, which is not even remotely the same thing if we make $\rho_2=\rho_{Water}$. This seems to be a case of a century (or more) of copying without thinking.

Comment: @CuriousOne I have inserted my book's page containing this argument please see it.

Comment: As written that's very sloppy and IMHO false. The formula is an approximation for the relative density between the solid and water, but it's not a proper definition of "relative density". Density is always mass divided by volume and mass is always completely independent of buoyancy. One should not mix the two in a physics textbook. The proper way to introduce relative density would be with masses and volumes alone and then one could mention that an approximate(!) method of determining this quantity with the hydrostatic method is given by the formula in your book.

Comment: I am just wondering who has written such a textbook! Why they are not teaching physics systematically???

Comment: @CuriousOne, the relative density definition given above is valid for solids (and liquids) only. If you want to measure the relative density of air, you need to use the expression for relative density of gases.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I taught high school physics for 13 years, and in my opinion, it's not a good idea to try teaching physics to 9th graders, who haven't learned enough math yet, and whose brain hasn't developed enough yet, to learn the concepts behind Newtonian mechanics.  And I also note that the concept of relative density is "watered down" nonsense, which is a concept that is going to be difficult to "beat out of" those 9th graders when they see physics later on.  My experience is that the first erroneous concept that people learn is the most difficult to correct later on.

Answer (score 1):

The method can only be used to measure the relative density of something more dense than water, otherwise the object will float.

The loss of weight of the object in water is the upthrust $U$ on the body, from Archimedes' principle (the same as the weight of water displaced).

[image]

The weight can be measured by a spring balance, equivalent to the tension in the string.

The tension in the right hand diagram is reduced by $U$, so

$$\frac{mg}{m_Wg} = \frac{mg}{U}$$

where $m_W$ is the weight of the water of the same volume.  The left hand side of this equation is the first formula, the right hand side is the second formula.

In practical terms the relative density is then determined by measurements of the tension from the spring balance

$$RD = \frac{T_A}{T_A-T_B}$$

since $mg = T_A$ and $U = mg-T_B = T_A-T_B$

i.e. the weight in air, divided by the loss of weight when immersed in water.

Answer (score 0):

The 'catch point' is that Relative density of a substance is relative to another material-say water;  strictly speaking its the ratio of two densities ; if RD=1, the densities are equal;  RD is a number , if RD<1 the body floats in water.

In Laboratories if somebody weighs a particular Volume of a substance say V (V.density.g)and again weighs the sample immersed in water -the loss in weight is equal to weight of the same volume of water(V.density of water.g) as the sample is -  thereby
one gets the RD as given in the book.

Actually the reference provided is a book on conducting experiment to determine the relative density of a material/substance  with respect to a reference substance and in the above case its taken as 'water'.

The relative density of a substance is  a ratio of density of particular substance with that of a reference . Sometimes we also use the term "specific gravity " when the reference material is taken as water.

So the term RD is ratio of two densities but many a time it can be easily calculated /measured by taking  a chosen quantity (sample) of the material and using good physical  balance

The sample is weighed first in air and then in water and use the following relationship-

Relative Density = Weight  in air /( Weight in air - weight  in water)

(the referred formula talks of denominator as "loss of weight in water"

This technique  can also be used in the labs to find RD of substances which float in water , meaning thereby whose RD is less than 1 using Nicholson Hydrometer (e.g. RD of cork)

Just for info:

> Another practical method uses three measurements. 
>   The sample is weighed dry. Then a container filled to the brim with water is weighed, and weighed again with the sample immersed, after the displaced water has overflowed and been removed. 
>   Subtracting the last reading from the sum of the first two readings gives the weight of the displaced water. 
>   The relative density result is the dry sample weight divided by that of the displaced water. This method works with scales that can't easily accommodate a suspended sample, and also allows for measurement of samples that are less dense than water.
>   for details visit :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_density

Answer (score 0):

Relative density of a solid is the ratio of density of solid to that of water:

$$\rho_r=\frac{\rho_{solid}}{\rho_{water}}$$

Now, according to Archimedes' principle, the weight of an object in a liquid seems to be reduced due to the upthrust, and this reduced weight is termed as apparent weight. There is no actual loss in mass of the solid. The buoyant force exerted on the object will be equal to the weight of the water displaced.

At this point, you should carefully note that the weight of the water displaced never equals the weight of the body, but equal to the buoyant force acting upwards.

$$W_A=W-W'$$

where $W_A$ is the apparent weight of the body, $W$ is the weight of the body in air, and $W'$ is the weight of the fluid displaced by the object. Now, the buoyant force is given by (assuming that the object is fully submerged in water)

$$F_B=W'=\rho_{water}V'g$$

where $V'$ is the volume of water submerged by the solid and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

Weight of the solid in air

$$W=\rho_{solid}Vg$$

Since the object is completely immersed in water, $V'=V$.

Now, $W/W'$ gives

$$\frac{W}{W'}=\frac{\rho_{solid}V}{\rho_{water}V'}=\rho_r$$

Now, to determine relative density experimentally, you need a spring balance. The weight you observe for the solid in air is $W$ and that you measure when the solid is completely immersed in water will be $W_A$. Rewriting $W'$ as $W-W_A$,

$$\rho_r=\frac{W}{W-W_A}$$

Hence, the formula in the textbook is right.